# Can't set transparency of LineSeries{}

Tags: qt, qml, transparency, opacity, lineseries

There is an application which contains ChartView{} with LineSeries{} inside it. I'm trying to set some transparency of the LineSeries{}.
First approach is with usage of "opacity":

```
LineSeries {
    id: lineId
    color: "red"
    opacity: 0.1
}
```

Second approach is with change of alpha:

```
LineSeries {
    id: lineId
    color: "red"
    Component.onCompleted: color = setColorAlpha(color, 0.1)
}
function setColorAlpha(color, alpha) {
    return Qt.hsla(color.hslHue, color.hslSaturation, color.hslLightness, alpha)
}
```

With both approaches there is no visible transparency, but for other objects they are OK.

Comment: The right property is [opacity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-abstractseries.html#opacity-prop) and should work as expected. Can you please provide [mcve] so we can check it?

Comment: My project is based on example project "Qml oscilloscope", so I just tested this example project how will react on property "opacity: 0.1". Again there is no visible change. Please, load this project and add to it property "opacity".

Comment: removing `useOpenGL` solves the issue. Probably due to performance the opacity isn't supported. From the docs: _It is optimized for efficiency, and therefore the series using it lack support for many features ..._

Comment: folibis, thank you very much!!!    It is ok now.